# Section filter of a net and filter generated by a net

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

From [Planetmath](http://planetmath.org/?method=src&from=objects&name=SectionFilter&op=getobj):

> Let $X$ be a set and $(x_i)_{i\in D}$ a non-empty net in $X$. For each
>   $j\in D$, define $S(j):=\lbrace x_i\mid i\le j\rbrace$. Then the set
>   $$S:=\lbrace S(j)\mid j\in D\rbrace$$ is a filter basis: $S$ is
>   non-empty because $(x_i)\neq \varnothing$, and **for any $j,k\in D$,
>   there is a $\ell$ such that $j\le \ell$ and $k\le \ell$, so that
>   $S(\ell) \subseteq S(j)\cap S(k)$**.
>
> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the family of all filters containing $S$.
>   $\mathcal{A}$ is non-empty since the filter generated by $S$ is in
>   $\mathcal{A}$. Order $\mathcal{A}$ by inclusion so that $\mathcal{A}$
>   is a poset. Any chain $\mathcal{F}_1\subseteq
>  \mathcal{F}_2\subseteq\cdots $ has an upper bound, namely,
>   $$\mathcal{F}:=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}_i.$$ By Zorn's
>   lemma, $\mathcal{A}$ has a maximal element $\mathcal{X}$.  $\mathcal{X}$ defined above is called the
>   **section filter of the net $(x_i)$ in $X$**.

1. I was wondering if the  sentence in bold is contrary to the
   definition of $S(j)$? Under that definition, it should be $S(\ell)
       \supseteq S(j)\cap S(k)$ instead, which means $S$ cannot be a filter basis.
2. Isn't the maximal element $\mathcal{X}$ always the
   power set of $X$?
3. How is the "section filter" of a net related to the filter
   generated by the net? The filter generated by a net $(x_i)_{i\in D}$
   that I found out elsewhere in the internet is defined as

   > For each $j \in D$, define $x_j := \{x_i : i ≥ j\}$. The collection of
   >   tails $\{x_j : j ∈ D\}$ is a ﬁlterbase on $X$.  The ﬁlter generated by
   >   this ﬁlterbase is called the ﬁlter generated by the net.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that $S(j)$ has been defined incorrectly: the definition should read $$S(j):=\{x_i:j\le i\}\;.$$ In other words, you want to look at the family of tails. It’s probably just a typo, either for $\{x_i:j\le i\}$ or for $\{x_i:i\ge j\}$. In short, it **is** the filter generated by the net in the sense of the other definition that you quoted.

Note that $\mathcal{X}$ can’t be $\wp(X)$, since $\mathcal{X}$, being a filter, can’t contain $\varnothing$. More generally, it can’t contain any set disjoint from an $S(j)$, since it definitely contains every $S(j)$.

Comment: I don't think I've seen anyone use `\wp` for power set before. Isn't it usually only used for [Weierstrass' elliptic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions)?

Comment: @kahen: I prefer to reserve $\mathscr{P}$ for other purposes, so I use $\wp$ for the power set.

Comment: Well... there's also $\mathcal P$ (`\mathcal P`)

Comment: @kahen: Which is just plain ugly. :-) I dislike the mathcal font, and $\wp$ actually looks a lot like my handwritten power set symbol.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks! (1) "it is the filter generated by the net in the sense of the other definition that you quoted", do you mean $S$ is the filter base generated by the net? (2) Is the filter generated by a net the minimal one containing the filter base generated by the net? (3) Is the section filter $\mathcal{X}$ of the net $(x_i)$ in $X$ usually not the same as the filter generated by the net?

Comment: (4) "Note that X can’t be ℘(X), since X, being a filter, can’t contain ∅", so does it mean the section filter generated by a net must be a proper filter ?